# How should I compare two list with repeating values in Python

Tags: python

How can I compare each item on list1 to list2 or to list3

```
list1 = [1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1]
list2 = [1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1]
list3 = [1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0]

for item1 in list1:
     for item2 in list2:
          if item1 == item2:
               *Output percentage of similarity
```

Comment: What is your desired output? Output `True` only if `list1` and `list2` have the same number of elements and the elements are all the same?

Comment: Do you just want to check where values are repeated in other lists?

Comment: Im looking for how similar one list is compared to another list

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by 3 lists at once and similarity. `sum(x==y for (x,y) in zip(list1, list2))/len(list1)` will give you a percentage for two lists (assuming same length), but how do you want the third list to influence?

Comment: You need to be more specific about what your definition of similar is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Code:**

```
list1 = [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1]
list2 = [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
list3 = [1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]

result = [list1[i] == list2[i] == list3[i] for i in range(len(list1))]
```

**Output:**

```
[True, True, True, False, False, True, True, False]
```

Comment: Yea list comprehension is nicer than a for loop.
@Joe Lanzi: You could then do `result_list.count(True)` to count the amount of `True`'s

Comment: @MarcelB, to count "True's" better to use `sum`. Example: `sum(list1[i] == list2[i] == list3[i] for i in range(len(list1)))`

Comment: Nice, didn't know sum will count True's =D

Comment: @MarcelB, `True` is [constant](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#boolean-values) in python3 and it equals `1`.

Comment: Thanks guys, this is what I'm looking for. Sorry I wasn't more specific, I'm new to python and stack overflow

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you want your expected output to be, but this will return a list comparing each of the values in each list. It uses the ZIP function. If you are not familiar with that, please lookup ZIP documentation.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    list1 = [1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1]
    list2 = [1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1]
    list3 = [1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0]

    returnList = []
    for a, b, c in zip(list1, list2, list3):
        if a == b == c:
            returnList.append(True)
        else:
            returnList.append(False)

    print(returnList)
```

Output:

```
[True, True, True, False, False, True, True, False]
```

Lastly, if you want an easy way to compare if all of the values match in every list (not that this was your original question, but it may be helpful depending on what you're going for), you can use the `all` function:

```
if all(returnList):
    print("ALL LISTS ARE EQUAL")
else:
    print("Differences exists between the lists.")
```

The `all` function will return true if every item in the list evaluates as `True`.

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1]
list2 = [1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1]
list3 = [1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0]
```

You probably want to iterate through the lists via indexing.
Also, if you're only handling 1's and 0's, even if they're integers, in python they're implicitly `True`or `False`.

```
for index in range(len(list1)):
    el1 = list1[index]
    el2 = list2[index]
    el3 = list3[index]
    # put any boolean logic here
    if el1 and el2 and el3:
        print(f"All elements are the same for index {index}.")
    if (el1 and el2) or (el1 and el3):
        print(f"Element el1 is equal to el2 or el2 or both for index {index}")
```